# powershell v2 - find a file in a directory and rename it

Tags: powershell-2.0, file-rename

I'm trying to write a simple script that allows me to check a directory, and find any matching filenames.
Once I find a match, I simply want to append the curent datetime to the front of the filename.

This sounds easy, but I can't quite figure it out

So far I have got

```
$directory = "c:\directoryName\"
$filename = "filename.log"
$d = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMddHHmm" 

get-childitem -Path $cfg_logDirectory | foreach-object 
{ 
    if ($_.name -eq $cfg_fileName)
        {
            $fname = $_.name
            Rename-Item -NewName $d."_".$fname
        }
}
```

But When I run this (in ISE at least), I get a window comes up asking me for

> "Cmdlet ForEach-Object at Command pipeline position 2 - Supply values
>   for the following parameters: Process[0]"

Is this the way to go, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your opening curly brace to the end of the previous line.

```
get-childitem -Path $cfg_logDirectory | foreach-object {
```

You're getting that error because Powershell is assuming the end of the line is the end of the statement, and then trying to prompt you for the missing parameter to foreach-object - in this case, its script block*.  Moving the opening brace to the same line tells Powershell that there are more statements coming.

*Why 'Process'?  The foreach-object cmdlet can take three script blocks as parameters: `Begin`, `Process`, and `End`.  Begin and End are optional, but Process is required.  If you supply a script block without a name, it is assumed to be Process.

Comment: and here's me thinking I was being clever. . . cheers for that it got rid of the process[] window. Does the rename-item section look right, because at present it's not renaming the file.

Comment: Your NewName string is malformed.  Try `Rename-Item -NewName "$d_$fname"`.  String concatenation in Powershell is `+`, not `.`, but you don't even need it here because you can just evaluate the variables inside the string.